# Starting powershell window with a command from java

Tags: java, windows, powershell

I want wo start powershell window from java application with a command. Cmd is blocked by our company policy.

I've tried

```
new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "start \"servicemix\" powershell -noexit -command \"dir\"").start();
```

However it does not open new window. The only way i've managed to open powershell window was with

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("full/path/to/powershell"));
```

But i haven't figured out a way how can i automatically run command in that window.

OS: windows

Comment: Are you certain company policy allows what you want to do?

Comment: Not sure, however i'm able to execute commands in powershell in background, just can't open powershell window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
new ProcessBuilder(
  "powershell.exe", 
  "Start-Process powershell.exe '-NoExit \"[Console]::Title = ''servicemix''; Get-ChildItem\"'"
).start();
```

Your own attempt tried to use the syntax of the `cmd.exe`-internal `start` command (which cannot be used from PowerShell except via an explicit call to `cmd.exe`), whereas PowerShell's `start` is an *alias* for its [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), whose syntax differs (and it doesn't support passing a window title, hence the inclusion of `[Console]::Title = ...` as a command to execute in the new PowerShell session).

Similarly, `dir` is an alias for PowerShell's [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet.

Note that I've removed `-Command` for brevity, because it is the *implied* parameter when you pass commands to `powershell.exe`, the [Windows PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe). Also note that `pwsh.exe`, the [PowerShell (Core) 7+ CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), now *requires* use of `-Command` (or `-c`, for short) if you pass commands, because it now defaults to `-File` in the interest of Unix compatibility.